# how to set proxy in wifi router Or Packet Routing

Tags: proxy, routing, ethernet, webserver

Scenario Is 2 Nic In Ubuntu14.04 Server, one with D-Link Router and One Direct Line of ISP. Now I Want all Request Of Router On Server.Router Is In Bridge Mode For Avoid Nat.when i setup Proxy in Router Connected Device I Got all Request But I dont Want To Set Proxy in Clients Device So I Setup Iptables Command. But I Got Unsupported Request ! So Is There Any Problem In Networking Ya In Iptables DNAT ?

Comment: Your question is barely legible. Please use proper capitalization and structure the text.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set up a [transparent proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Transparent_proxy), you need a proxy server software that supports it. That’s because a “captured” connection is different from how the browser would normally talk to a (regular) proxy.

First, you install your proxy, Squid in this case, and verify it works as a regular proxy.

Then, you set it to accept captured connections:

```
http_port 3128 transparent
```

After that, all you need is a firewall rule to actually capture connections:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
```

This configuration doesn’t work if the proxy is on another host. In that case, you’d use DNAT.

Please note that transparent proxies can’t work with HTTPS unless they perform a MITM attack. Otherwise it wouldn’t know where the connection is supposed to go. SSL interception is not a good idea unless you know what you’re doing.